# how do I add N days to time T (accounting for Daylight Savings Time)?

Tags: ruby, time

I have a Time object T.  What's a reasonable way to add N days to T?

The best I've come up with feels somewhat tortured:

```
require 'date'
def add_days(time, days)
  time.to_date.next_day(days).to_time
end
```

P.S.: If you are in the US, a correct answer must satisfy:

```
add_days(Time.new(2013, 3, 10, 0), 1) == Time.new(2013, 3, 11, 0)
```

and if you are in the EU, a correct answer must satisfy:

```
add_days(Time.new(2013, 3, 31, 0), 1) == Time.new(2013, 4, 1, 0)
```

P.P.S: This is a Ruby question, not a Rails question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) seems to handle this well

```
> t1 = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse('2013-03-10')
 => Sun, 10 Mar 2013 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Notice the class type below:

```
 > t1.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Notice the change from EST above to EDT below:

```
> t1 + 1.day
 => Mon, 11 Mar 2013 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Comment: Can actually just do this: `t1 = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse('2013-03-12').dst?` The key is the `Eastern Time`. If you use `EST` or `EDT`, like I was doing, it will always show in those time zones whether or not `ET` is currently in `DST` or not.

Comment: Good answer, though I was originally asking about a Ruby environment that didn't have ActiveSupport.  Now that things are better modularized, it would be reasonable to include standalone ActiveSupport to get this functionality.

Comment: Note to everybody who doesn't want it to adjust, you can convert it to utc before adding the time then convert it back, since utc does not have daylight savings
`(datetime.utc + 1.weeks).to_datetime # will not adjust`

Answer (score 12):

`Time` has a [`+` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-2B) which accepts seconds.

```
N = 3

t = Time.now + N * 86400 # 24 * 60 * 60
```

Or, if you bring ActiveSupport in, it's easier

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

t = Time.now + N.days
```

You can obviously make your own helper

```
class Fixnum
  def days
    self * 86400
  end
end

t = Time.now # => 2013-01-31 16:06:31 +0700

t + 3.days # => 2013-02-03 16:06:31 +0700
```

Comment: Adding seconds like that will give the wrong answer across DST boundaries

Comment: @FrederickCheung: ah, didn't think about that. But it's simpler. Also, it satisfies OP's specification. Please, feel free to add your answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: your answer does not satisfy the original spec -- try it out on the 'correct answer must satisfy' to see what I mean.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: on the other hand, are you sure about DST? Could you provide a snippet with a problem?

Comment: Well that's perplexing.  What time zone are you in?  (More to the point: when is your DST / ST transition?)

Comment: @fearless_fool: returns true for me. ruby 1.9.3 p374 on latest osx.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: ah!  If you're in the EU, try: `Time.new(2013, 3, 31, 0) + 86400 == Time.new(2013, 4, 1, 0)` and let me know what happens.

Comment: @fearless_fool: I am in Thailand now, so it returns true :)

Comment: "when is your DST / ST transition?" - I have no idea, really :)

Comment: Got that.  But Frederick Cheung is correct: simply adding multiples of 86400 seconds to a time object won't work properly for regions that observe daylight savings (thus the original title of this question).

Comment: @fearless_fool: ah! noticed it just now!

Answer (score 6):

As appears to have become my style, I am answering my own question.

Since the transition across DST / ST is rather rare (and in many parts of the world, nonexistent), a more efficient approach is to first add (n_days * 24 * 60 * 60) seconds and then check if the UTC offset has changed.  If it has, then create a corrected time object.

Like this:

```
def add_days(time, n_days)
  t2 = time + (n_days * 24 * 60 * 60)
  utc_delta = time.utc_offset - t2.utc_offset
  (utc_delta == 0) ? t2 : t2 + utc_delta
end
```

This approach and avoids a lot of extra object creation, and handles transitions across Daylight Savings properly (at least in my current time zone, Pacific Time):

```
>> t1 = Time.new(2013, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0)
=> 2013-03-10 00:00:00 -0800  # midnight Mar 3, 2013 Pacific Standard Time
>> t2 = add_days(t1, 1)
=> 2013-03-11 00:00:00 -0700  # midnight Mar 4, 2013 Pacific Daylight Time
>> t2 - t1
=> 82800.0                    # a shorter than usual day

>> u1 = Time.new(2013, 11, 3, 0, 0, 0)
=> 2013-11-03 00:00:00 -0700  # midnight Nov 3, 2013 Pacific Daylight Time
>> u2 = add_days(u1, 1)
=> 2013-11-04 00:00:00 -0800  # midnight Nov 4, 2013 Pacific Standard Time
>> u2 - u1
=> 90000.0                    # a longer than usual day
```

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat of a lateral answer but because in your original question you weren't concerned about the HMS section of `Time`, wouldn't you be better off using `Date` objects instead?

```
require 'date'
t=Time.now
d=Date.parse(t.to_s)
puts d+1 # => gives you tomorrow's day (YMD)
```

**Edit:** Added `require 'date'` to improve answer comprehensiveness, as pointed out in the comments section.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Though, one must `require 'date'` before calling the Date.parse method.